# How do I change background image's size in compositor?

Tags: node-editor, interface, image, compositing-nodes

How can I change background image's size in compositor?

The following screenshots are showing my node setup and the current size of the background image.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: [Problem A](https://https://imgur.com/a/nvEgKZy)   [Problem B](https://https://imgur.com/a/fWqj3Ea) [Problem C](https://https://imgur.com/a/t8iXqOs) [Problem D](https://https://imgur.com/a/6HOYpzW)

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please let us know if the linked q/a does not solve your issue and explain why in detail by editing your question, thanks. Also, I'd recommend take the [tour] to learn about how this site works.